# Prefilling SMS based on device type (IOS, Android, etc)

Tags: javascript, android, ios, sms

I have two buttons on a webpage that allow the user to call or text the displayed record in our database.

```
<a style="..." href="tel:<%= model.get('phone_alternate').split("-").join("") %>">Make a Call</a>
<a style="..." href="sms:<%= model.get('phone_alternate').split("-").join("") %>">Send a Text</a>
```

I'd like to populate the SMS message using the second button, but since IOS doesn't use the same format as others, using the `?body=message` won't work for all of my users (it'd need to be `;body=message` instead).

In trying to find a resultion, I came across this page...[Prefilling an SMS on Mobile Devices...](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/Oct/09/Prefilling-an-SMS-on-Mobile-Devices-with-the-sms-Uri-Scheme) but don't quite understand how to implement it in my setting.

His code shows:

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var url;

if (ua.indexOf("iphone") > -1 || ua.indexOf("ipad") > -1)
    url = "sms:;body=" + encodeURIComponent("I'm at " + mapUrl + " @ " + pos.Address);
else
    url = "sms:?body=" + encodeURIComponent("I'm at " + mapUrl + " @ " + pos.Address);

location.href = url;
```

...but where would I put this in my page to have it work?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who stumbles across this question in the future, I was able to accomplish it very easily with...

`<a href="sms:15555555555;?&body=Message%20Text%20Here">Send a Text</a>` with the `?&` allowing it to work on both IOS and Android.